# Getting value from drop down box filled by GetAllMembers()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm have a little difficulty with drop down boxes that are filled with Membership.GetAllUsers();

I have the following code which sucessfully puts all users into a drop down list

```
UsrList.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers(); //get all users
UsrList.DataBind(); //bind
```

I then have a button that should store the username currently in the drop down list to a string, however it just always stores the first value in the drop down list.

```
string usr = UsrList.SelectedItem.Value;
Label3.Text = usr;
```

I'm sure theres something very simple im missing, any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the selectedItem.Value I think you will need to define the DataTextField and DataTextValue

```
UsrList.DataTextField = "<Property to display>";
UsrList.DataValueField = "<Property to use as Value>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pedro's direct answer above, you may also want to slightly modify your list items.  Here is the code to add a "default" item as the top item in the list:

protected void UsrList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      UsrList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" ", "0"));
  }

and Front side add to the control:
OnDataBound="UsrList_DataBound"

You can always modify the method above to select a particular value from the list, also.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your first snippet of code is being executed prior to the second in the Page Lifecycle.

Make sure you set the `DataSource` and `DataBind()` in `Page_Load`, and retrieve the `UsrList.SelectedItem.Value` in a UI event like `Button_OnClick`

The ASP.NET Page Lifecycle is roughly

- Begin Request

  - Page_Init
  - Page_Load
  - Load Posted Data From Request
  - Process Events
  - Create ViewState
  - Render
- End Request

I hope this helps.